# android google maps sdk geolocation VS cordova geolocation

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, geolocation

I'm using google maps javascript library to embed map in cordova application and I'm using cordova API to get geolocation my problem is that if I set high accuracy to true than it becomes very slow. if I decrease timeout then I'm getting lots of timeout errors.
I guess high accuracy is using satellites to get location

I want to track users movement similarly to maps application inside android and when I compare these two, native maps application in android behaves much better so I think it is also using some sensor fusion technologies

my question is that if I rewrite application to use google maps android sdk will I get same location tracking quality as native maps application in android ? or will it be better than simple cordova Geolocation calls at least ?

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question?